# Some confusion between ASP.NET 4.0 and 2.0

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to make a website in C# ASP.NET.  I have been given some code as well as visual studio 2010.  The code I was given was written in ASP.NET 4.0, so I obviously want to code in that, but my web hosting only supports ASP.NET 2.0.  If I upgrade to 4.0 what's the difference as far as compatibility issues with all browsers, or any draw backs to using 4.0.  I am using 1&1 hosting so it is a pretty commercial hosting, maybe there is a reason why they do not have 4.0 standard on their servers?  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hosting company doesn't offer 4.0, your applications will not run.

The runtime is different, the configuration is different. There are too many differences for things to work out of the box.

Most hosts will let you have a virtual server for a higher cost, where you can install anything you want (within limit), so ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

the browsers have nothing to do with asp.net compatibility.
asp.net 4.0 still does not have widespread availability because it is pretty new, but it is rock solid stable and it is generally recommended over asp.net 2.0

Comment: Even if you can't host it anywhere?